# Is the original nation of Amalek extinct?

Tags: history, amalek

Is it inaccurate to say that the nation of amalek is extinct?

Comment: What do you mean by extinct?

Comment: See https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/961561/jewish/Positive-Commandment-187.htm

Answer (score 1):

In [Kol HaTor 2:36](https://www.sefaria.org/Kol_HaTor.2.36) (which is attributed to the GR"A) it states:

> לו) **הרחיבי מקום אהלך וכו׳** (ישעי׳ כ״ד) – מצות הרחבת הגבולים הוא
> בתפקידו של משיב״י כדבר ה׳ אל יונה הנביא שהוא היה במעליתא דמשיח בן
> יוסף, להשיב גבול ישראל (מלכים ב י״ד:כ״ה). וכן מן המיצר למרחביה שתפקידו
> הרחבת הגבולים במלחמתו נגד עמלק שהוא המחריב כפי המדרש: האויב תמו חרבות
> לנצח על הפסוק: מלחמה לה׳ בעמלק מרחיב נגד מחריב.
>
> (Isa. 54:2) **“expand the site of your tent, ” etc**. -- The
> commandment to expand the borders is the mission of Mashiach ben Yosef
> as God had told the prophet Jonah, who was on the level of Mashiach
> ben Yosef, to restore the border of Israel (II Kings 14:25). Likewise
> the verse: “in distress...in expansiveness, ” means that it was his
> mission to expand the boundaries in the war against Amalek, who was
> the destroyer, according to the Midrash. “The enemy, the destructions
> are gone forever” which is related to the verse: “God wages war
> against Amalek.” The verb “expands” is used in opposition to the verb
> “destroys” [the order of the letters and are in reverse order in the
> two words].

According to this quote they are most certainly still alive.